# Trackingpixel Magento 2 Succedd page, GrandTotal is 0.00

Tags: magento2, checkout, affiliate

Just implemented tracking pixel for our affiliate program, but Grand_total is reportes as 0.00 every time.

Anyone can give mee a helping hand on this?

My success.phtml contains:

```
<div class="checkout-success">
<div class="success-title">
    <p><span class="success-title-icon">icon</span></p>
    <p><span><?php echo __('Thank you!') ?></span></p>
</div>
<?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
    <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
        <p><?php echo __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a class="order-id" href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
    <?php  else :?>
        <p><?php echo __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
        <p><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
<?php endif;?>


<script src="https://online.adservicemedia.dk/cgi-bin/API/ConversionService/js?camp_id=0000&order_id=<?php echo $block->getOrderId(); ?>&amount=<?php echo $grand_total; ?>&cur=<?php echo $currencysymbol; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript><img src="https://online.adservicemedia.dk/cgi-bin/API/ConversionService/p?camp_id=0000" width="1" height="1" border="0"></noscript>


<?php echo $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

<div class="primary">
    <a class="action primary continue" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't assign value to `$grand_total` variable. Please assign subtotal value to that variable and try again.